# How can I locate my Android device around the house?

Tags: lost-phone

Oftentimes, I don't know where I placed my Android around the house. Is there a way to make it vibrate and emit high volume sounds/music that will help me find it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Four come to mind:

1. [Phoning Pigeon](http://www.appbrain.com/app/phoning-pigeon/com.lionebra.phoningpigeon)
2. [Where's My Droid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/wheres-my-droid/com.alienmanfc6.wheresmyandroid)
3. [Lookout Mobile](http://www.appbrain.com/app/lookout-mobile-security/com.lookout)
4. [Prey](http://www.appbrain.com/app/prey-phone-tracker/com.prey)

Each goes about it in different ways. *Phoning Pigeon* probably has the lightest touch. You pre-define one or more phone numbers with the app. Then, if the phone receives two consecutive calls from one of those numbers, it will turn the ringer on at maximum volume.

*Where's My Droid* is similar, but you send an SMS message with specific text.

The *Lookout* siren is **very** loud; you'd have no trouble finding it. The app has several other functions as well, including virus scanning and backing up your data.

*Prey* is similar to Lookout's tracking and probably wouldn't be as useful for finding a misplaced phone in your house; it's more for tracking a phone that has been taken. It might work for you, though, and there's no risk in checking it out.

Comment: +1 for Lookout - it does quite a bit more than just allow you to find your phone.

Answer (score 11):

Use the Phone function of your wife's phone, to, erm , phone it.

Comment: Not much help when the phone is on vibrate.

Answer (score 1):

Lookout is free and works well.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I expect because Lookout was already mentioned in a previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you've lost the phone *before* you remembered to install one of the mentioned apps, you have one more option: [Plan B](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb) (from the same people who developed Lookout).

Basically you install it *after* the phone goes missing and trigger it via text message.

Comment: [PlanB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb) is showing only support for Android 2.0 - 2.3. Sure would be nice if support was broader, excellent idea though.

Answer (score 1):

The best  simple, official app to locate your lost phone is Android Device Manager. You can register as many phones as you want with it.

[image: IMG:]    [image: IMG:]

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score -3):

I use [wheresmycellphone.com](http://www.wheresmycellphone.com/), rather than downloading an app. Works great!

Comment: How is that different than just calling it from a different phone?

Comment: And how do I know that this site isn't just for harvesting cell phone numbers?

Comment: And what if your cell phone is just in "silent mode"? Nothing will ring then. No sound is played. It might not even vibrate.