# Find my Android from an App

Tags: lost-phone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An app to locate my Android device around the house?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2603/an-app-to-locate-my-android-device-around-the-house)

I'm looking for a "find my phone" app that can be activated from another app instead of a webpage.

The scenario is simple, my wife misplaces her android phone frequently. I'd like to be able to quickly launch an app from my android phone or tablet and activate a find me siren on her device. So far all of the apps I've found require you to long into a bloated webpage first.

Edit: It should work in reverse too, so I can find my tablet (which does not have a phone number of course) from her phone.

Comment: It's not a exact duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2603/an-app-to-locate-my-android-device-around-the-house because I am specifically looking for an app that works from app to app (like apple's find my device app) without needing one of the devices to be a phone or needing to visit a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Find My Phone Siren" does what I was looking for (app to app siren). It also uses google to sign in so you don't need yet another account. Only drawback is that it costs $1.97.

Answer (score 5):

If that's your scenario ... just call her on her android phone? Maybe she can put you a siren as your personal ringtone.

Answer (score 1):

[Phoning Pigeon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lionebra.phoningpigeon)

You don't need to install it, but she does. Set your phone number to be one of the activating phone numbers. When you call her phone two consecutive times it takes the phone out of silent mode, making it then easy to call it a third time so it can be found.

Answer (score 0):

[Prey](http://preyproject.com) is another possibility. It goes beyond the world of Android, even.

You can use the Prey app on your device to monitor your other devices. Technically, though, this will fail one of your criteria as it really just launches the Prey website. (It's not, however, "bloated".)