# Locating lost android device in home

Tags: lost-phone

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [An app to locate my Android device around the house?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2603/an-app-to-locate-my-android-device-around-the-house)
>   [My phone was just stolen an hour or so ago. Are there any options for tracking?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18644/my-phone-was-just-stolen-an-hour-or-so-ago-are-there-any-options-for-tracking)

Ok so i lost my Samsung Galaxy player 4.0 somewhere in my house. It was connected to Wi-Fi. And i've heard that i can track devices that are connected to my router, how do i do so?
Router- Belkin Play N600. Please Help!

Comment: The best tracking you'll get is just that it is in your home.  Does it have upnp - perhaps you could stream music to it?

Comment: you need to have installed an app before you lose it to track a device, and you are not going to get pin point accuracy. You would be lucky to close to your house let alone telling you if its currently under your left side cushion of the love seat.

Answer (score 5):

Install [Plan B](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb) using the web version of Google play. Trigger it with a text message to sound an alarm.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest deploying the mk.1 human child.

Tell them if they find it you'll buy them a treat.

...I'm serious. It's alot easier than going technical.